# Interpreting the van der Waals Energy Discrepancy between $\rm MoS_2$ and Graphene Layers in Computational Simulations

Tags: energy, computational-physics, graphene, nanoscience

I am conducting computational simulation tests and have observed that when simulating systems like molybdenum disulfide ($\rm MoS_2$), the interaction between layers (S-S interaction) is quite strong, preventing the system from 'sliding' in comparison to others, such as graphene, for instance. To substantiate this hypothesis, I thought about measuring the van der Waals energy between graphene layers (bilayer) and, separately, between $\rm MoS_2$ layers. When calculating the energy per atom, the vdW energy is lower for $\rm MoS_2$ than for graphene, both being positive. I am having difficulty interpreting this issue – does the lower energy imply a stronger bond in the system? Additionally, unlike graphene, $\rm MoS_2$ has half of the sulfur atoms in one layer interacting with half of the sulfur atoms in the other layer. Should I only consider the vdW energy for the groups of atoms that are interacting?